# Axiom of choice needed? finite sets

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I have to show that the following 2 quotes are equivalent:
a) The set A is finite
b) Every injective function from A to A is also surjective

The direction a) ==> b):
I've worked with induction on the cardinality of A and just definied the function

The direction b) ==> a):
I've got no idea! I would begin with: Presume that A is infinite.. But I'dont see what to do.

Thanks in advance
Silke

Comment: Yes, the axiom of choice is needed. Show that if $A$ is infinite, it contains a countably infinite subset.

Comment: Because A is infinite, there's an injective function from the natural numbers to A. And if we work with the image, then we get a countably infinite subset?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo  Is the axiom of choice really necessary for that purpose? Seems a very straightforward constructive procedure of just successively taking elements out of $A$.

Comment: @Silke  Are you equipped with the standard example on $\mathbb{Z}$ involving shifts?

Comment: @Evan: It is true that we can remove any finite number of elements from $A$ in this way. However, this does not mean that we can remove countably-infinitely-many elements from $A$ in this way. How do we make infinitely-many arbitrary choices? A little bit of the Axiom of Choice is needed here.

Comment: @CameronBuie  Whoops! I (sort of ) see now from reading similar posts. Seems so innocent...

Comment: @Evan: It is a ***very*** common blunder.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the axiom of choice is in fact needed for this equivalence.

We say that a set $A$ is **Dedekind-finite** if every injection from $A$ into $A$ is a bijection. And it is consistent that the axiom of choice fails and there are infinite Dedekind-finite sets.

For example, it is consistent that such set is dense in the real numbers.

One useful equivalent is that $A$ is Dedekind-infinite (i.e. *not* Dedekind-finite) if and only if it has a countably infinite subset. In particular, when we assume the axiom of choice every infinite set has a copy of $\Bbb N$ inside. From this copy we can generate an injection which is not a bijection.